# Convert timezone in Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: sql, azure, azure-synapse, sql-data-warehouse

I have a DATETIME column from the `US/Pacific` timezone, but it is not encoded as such. How can I convert this to `UTC` timezone in Azure SQL Data Warehouse?

The `AT DATETIME` T-SQL function seems like the closest fit, but it is not supported by Azure SQL Data Warehouse.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql

For example, one record has a DATETIME of `2013-04-02 08:02:47.000000`. After conversion it should be `2013-04-02 15:02:47.000000`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because my data were stored in 'US/Pacific' I used `TODATETIMEOFFSET()` to add the specific offset to the data. Once stored as a `DATETIMEOFFSET` type, it is treated as UTC time by the server but the timezone offset is still available.

`SELECT TODATETIMEOFFSET(time_in_pt, '-08:00') as time_with_pt_timezone ...`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/todatetimeoffset-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

it's a little hard to answer with no context, but i believe you could just [cast or convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) the column to whatever [date/time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql) type you desire. Accounting for the timezone is hard to say, yet again, with a lack of context.

Answer (score 0):

Right now (in winter) we are in PST which is UTC – 8 hours. So converting your date 2013-04-02 08:02:47.000000 to UTC will be 2013-04-02 16:02:47.0000000 value.

declare @mydate datetime2 = '2013-04-02 08:02:47.000000'
select dateadd(hh, 8, @mydate) as utcdate